# Are in a supercurrent superconducting electrons separated (distinguishable) from normal electrons in the momentum space?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, condensed-matter, superconductivity

In some experiments a supercurrent, once established, runs for years and longer. At non-zero temperature, there are always normal and superconducting (SC) electrons in every superconductor. If SC-electrons were interchangeable with normal electrons, then the SC - electrons would become normal (dissipative) for a while, whereas the newly created SC - electrons did not experience any electromotive force. So the total current momentum (or angular momentum) would disappear and the supercurrent would inevitably stop (otherwise the momentum conservation law is violated; the atom lattice took the momentum Px of the “broken” initial SC-electrons, hence Px of the newly created SC-electrons must be zero). Thus, the SC – electrons cannot hop into normal states, i.e. the SC - electrons occupy the SC - states permanently in time. If so, then the SC - electrons must be distinguishable (separated) from the normal electrons in the momentum space.
We well know real-space-distinguishable particles; for example, electron 1 is permanently in area A and electron 2 is permanently in area B, separated from A by a strong potential. But electrons may be distinguishable in the momentum space, when electron 1 permanently occupies momentum state P1, electron 2 permanently occupies momentum state P2. For example: free single electrons and electrons of  helium atoms are not interchangeable below the helium ionization temperature, because the helium electrons cannot leave their 1s momentum states, and the free electrons cannot take the permanently occupied 1s states in helium. So the free band and 1s band are well separated by a gap and we can assert that the free electrons and helium electrons are distinguishable in the momentum space, although the wave functions of free electrons and helium electrons can overlap in the real space.
The question about distinguishable electrons is crucially important, since most theories of superconductivity consider electrons as indistinguishable particles belonging to one shared momentum space, where every electron can take every state with a non-zero probability. Should we consider the SC-electrons and normal electrons in a supercurrent as separated in the momentum space? Are SC-electrons and normal electrons realy distinguishable and non-interchangeable in the momentum space (like the electrons bound in helium atoms and free electrons)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Added a question clarification: Are SC-electrons and normal electrons realy distinguishable and non-interchangeable in the momentum space (like the electrons bound in helium atoms and free electrons)?